# What is NavigationServices.FirstOrDefault() of Template10 navigation service?

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I want to navigate between pages in Template10. From the documentation,
https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Services#navigationservice, the example is as follow

> // from inside any window var nav =
>   WindowWrapper.Current().NavigationServices.FirstOrDefault();
>   nav.Navigate(typeof(Views.DetailPage), this.Value);

Unfortunately WindowWrapper.Current().NavigationServices.FirstOrDefault() does not exist. What FirstOrDefault actually means?

Also, how do I navigate to other page from page.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault()` is an extension method provided by LINQ. You need to add the line:

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your file to get it.

Answer (score 3):

FirstOrDefault(); which is located as part of the Linq namespace as indicated by Colin Mackay, **returns the first entry in the collection (returns an Enumerable)... or Null as the "default" value of the queried result.**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx